# Getting invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist in docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-stack

I am trying to deploy following docker-compose into docker swarm cluster.

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./data_jenkins:/var/jenkins_home
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
```

I do have the **data_jenkins** in the same locations where docker-compose is and passing that path as volume . But why is it throwing the source path does not exist. What exactly is the problem.

> Also if the directory doesnot exist -v should have created it right.
>   Why is it not ?

Comment: This is the problem I have figured out. the path may be available in one of the cluster but not in another cluster. Running in manager node works. But why is the -v not creating a directory to whichever node it is running

Comment: For me, downgrading docker-compose version helped

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This is clearly documented in [Docker Swarm BIND MOUNTS](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/services/#bind-mounts)

> If you bind mount a host path into your service’s containers, **the path
>   must exist on every swarm node**. The Docker swarm mode scheduler can
>   schedule containers on any machine that meets resource availability
>   requirements and satisfies all constraints and placement preferences
>   you specify.

Unlike running a single container, the bind-mount **host** directory is not created if it doesn't exit. It must exist prior to running the container on a cluster node.

Comment: Absolutely thats what it is to solve the problem I have used named container instead of passing the host path. Thanks I was unaware of scheduler too. Accepted answer

Comment: @TaraPrasadGurung Could u please describe what did u do to solve the problem?

Comment: It is also possible to restrict the placement in the "deply" section to a specific server where the directory exists.

Comment: For those still struggling with this. I had to make sure the directory I wanted to bind mount into my container existed _relatively_ to my docker swam yml file. I was trying to create a bind mount from outside the context of the build/swarm directory which didn't work.