# Invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist:

Tags: linux, docker, shell, ubuntu, docker-swarm

I'm new to Docker and I'm trying to bind-mount using following command:

```
docker service create --mount type=bind,src=/mnt/c/Users/Elev/Desktop/iris,dst=/mnt/c/Users/Elev/Desktop/iris --name myservice1 myservice
```

and I'm getting following message:

```
image myservice:latest could not be accessed on a registry to record
its digest. Each node will access image:latest independently,
possibly leading to different nodes running different
versions of the image.

e32lbdbvn3meq5i4cpgsnes4m
overall progress: 0 out of 1 tasks
1/1: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /mn…
```

I'm able to cd to the '/mnt/c/Users/Elev/Desktop/iris' directory and I'm sure it exists. So why am I getting this error and how can this be fixed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48971065/getting-invalid-mount-config-for-type-bind-bind-source-path-does-not-exist-in)

Comment: @KapilKhandelwal no, not really